# Bootstrap side by side DIV

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Would somebody be able to tell me why the `div`s in this JSFiddle (Bootstrap CSS imported) are not side by side when the string of text in the second `div` is longer? I appreciate you taking the time to help me.

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/13602/

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-md-12'>
          <div style='display:inline-block;border:1px solid purple;'>
            whatever
          </div>
          <div style='display:inline-block;border:1px solid red;'>
          Why the heck do the divs stack on top of each other when this line gets really long?  I would think they would be side by side because the display property of the div is set to inline block
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I realize this does not answer your question directly, but why not col-md-6 both of them and wrap them in another row if needed?  That is what bootstrap is useful for after all.

Comment: I want the column on the left to be a fixed number of pixels and the the column on the right to take up the remainder of the screen, so this is not really an option.. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Flexbox actually served me proper, thank you for your help.**

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}

.flexcontainer {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
   flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
        <div class="flexcontainer">
              <div style='width: 50px; border:1px solid purple;'>
                whatever
              </div>
              <div style=' border:1px solid red;'>
              Why the heck do the divs stack on top of each other when this line gets really long?  I would think they would be side by side because the display property of the div is set to inline block
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width for inline-block. https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/13604/.

```html
<div style='display:inline-block; width: 20%; border:1px solid purple;'>
whatever
</div>
<div style='display:inline-block; width: 70%;border:1px solid red;'>
Why the heck do the divs stack on top of each other when this line gets really long?  I would think they would be side by side because the display property of the div is set to inline block
</div>
```

I recommend using the bootstrap grid instead of defining inline-block like the above. For example, `<div class="col-md-3>` etc. https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: This is interesting.  I did not realize setting the width like this would work.  Thank you for this information.  Unfortunately I want the column on the left to be a fixed width, and the column the right to fill the remainder of the width (100% of container).  I know I can use jquery to set the width of the second column (or possibly use flexbox), but this just seems a little hacky to me.

Comment: If you want one column to be fixed and the other to be responsive, flexbox would work. http://learnlayout.com/flexbox.html

Comment: yeah, I considered that.  Mixing flexbox and bootstrap seems like a sub-optimal solution to me, though.  I'll give that a try if nobody proposes a better solution.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe, it's because of `inline-block`. Try using just `inline`:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-md-12'>
          <div style='display:inline;border:1px solid purple;'>
            whatever
          </div>
          <div style='display:inline;border:1px solid red;'>
          Why the heck do the divs stack on top of each other when this line gets really long?  I would think they would be side by side because the display property of the div is set to inline block
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```