# Bootstrap div's not side by side

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am having trouble figuring out why my div's are not side by side...

I checked the following link but they do not answer my question...

[Bootstrap side by side DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319893/bootstrap-side-by-side-div)

Here is my code

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <br/><br/><br/>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <form>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Product</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                                <option>1</option>
                                <option>2</option>
                                <option>3</option>
                                <option>4</option>
                                <option>5</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Serial Number</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Problem Description</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

It has something to do with the `<form>` element, is there a class I am missing on that element?

Comment: Is this what you want https://www.bootply.com/GgGga0szpS?

Comment: yes it is =] thank you